# Transform and backface-visibility not working correctly in safari version 10.1 and chrome 73

Tags: css, animation, safari

I'm trying to make a flip circle on my jgraph js project. Everything working fine in chrome, edge, firefox. But when I try to test in Safari and chrome 73, the element does not display at all.

I'm using "backface-visibility" and "transform" in order to make the flip circle. I guess something is wrong with these CSS attribute in chrome 73 because if I remove these attributes then the element can display well (but no effect). In safari 10.1, the element can not display even when I already removed the css attribute. It only displays the element if I change the position from absolute to fixed (you can read my css code below).

```css
.counter-card {
    margin-left: 12%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center right;
    -webkit-transition:transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: center right;
    visibility:visible;
    border: red 1px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
}
.red-color {
    background: #dd4050;
}
.yellow-color {
    background: #f7e85c;
}
.purple-color {
    background: #823d84;
}
.green-color {
    background: #3eb763;
}
.counter-card.is-flipped {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-100%) rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform:translateX(-100%) rotateY(-180deg);
    -o-transform:translateX(-100%) rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card__face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    overflow: visible;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card__face--front {
    /* background: #DD4050; */
}

.card__face--back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Html:

```html
<div class="scene scene--card" style="width:80%;height:80%;">
 <div class="counter-card">
    <div class="card__face card__face--front red-color"></div>
    <div class="card__face card__face--back yellow-color"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add your HTML code too?

Comment: @NataliaDavydova Of course, I just have added HTML code.